# регулярное выражение чтобы достать текст после слова и внутри лапок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, perl

есть строка

```
name='asd',color='3',ids='1,2,2re'
```

мне надо достать `1,2,2re`

Comment: Regex: `/ids=\'(.*?)\'/`

Comment: `(?<=ids=')[^']+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Брать первую группу.

```
ids='([^']*)'
```

Comment: либо `ids='(.*?)'`

Comment: @teran, можно, но я предпочитаю более строгий вариант.